# Apple rejects app because test account not given (as App login via OTP only)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Apple rejected my app because I haven't provided a test account.
**My app has login option only via OTP**.
So, how to convince Apple about same.

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to
> continue because we need additional information about your app.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide
> detailed information to the following questions. The more information
> you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your review.
>
> - Please provide a demo mobile phone number and verification code for review
>
> Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested
> information, we can proceed with your review.

Comment: add the test account with out OTP in description part on itunesconnect page and resubmit your app, apple will continue the process

Comment: Why Vote Down ?

Comment: i m not assign downvote

Comment: I have already provided test account but once Apple log in, it asks for password, which will come only come to my mobile number, How to handle this?

Comment: are you understand , for testing purpose add one test account if your handle the test account skip the OTP process and do the continue process for your app, if OTP not receive the particular no how will check the app

Comment: @SamkitJain yes in your code just skip the OTP verfication process  and continue or u can skip it from backend also for the number u provide for login

Comment: Set your phone number as hard coded. And If Apple QA Team enter your mobile number, Than by default set OTP 1234

Comment: @iDeveloper Don't you think making things hardcoded on server side or client side is a Hack.

Comment: I vote to close this topic.  The nature of this topic opens little discussion because it's only the matter of providing Apple reviewer with more information.

Answer (score 15):

Assumed that, you are storing mobile number and saving OTP to your server side. So that, when user will enter his OTP code, then it will check with mobile number and give access to use the app.

Just execute below process:

1. Add on mobile number to server. for e.g. 123-456-0789
2. Assign static OTP to this number. for e.g. "1234"
3. Give same mobile number to Apple for review.
4. Now, when apple will review the app, they will enter mobile number as "123-456-0789" and he will receive message about OTP. (Just on screen, but don't send OTP to this number.
5. On OTP enter screen apple will enter "1234" which will verify to server and Apple can review the app.

Note:
No need to submit build again. Just inform that, demo account credential has been added.

Hope, this helps to move further for your app process.

Comment: This is brilliant, I never thought of that!