# iOS app: Rejected in AppStore to external testers

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, deployment, app-store

I need to get my iOS app (React Native) get approved to external testers. I am getting this message from Apple:

[image]

I know that I should provide login information(username and pass). But I have user's phone number as name and user can enter the pass only after he get the SMS with a security code.

Here's the complete flow:

1. User enters phone number
2. Gets SMS with code and enters it
3. Entering password
4. Proceeding to app

What should be done in this case? Can the Apple sign up and create the account, if I write a message to them, describing the flow?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple rejects app because test account not given (as App login via OTP only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453416/apple-rejects-app-because-test-account-not-given-as-app-login-via-otp-only)

Comment: You have login in your app. So provide them any account credentials for testing your app.

Comment: @AmirKhan But how can they get the security code?

Comment: @drevival are you using Firebase Auth?

Comment: @AmirKhan Nope. 2faAuth

Comment: @drevival ok, you can add static phone number and otp at their dashboard such as sandbox user and provide them to review team or you can do a trick with a specific number, i.e whenever they enter that phone number they will redirected to password screen means skip that OTP screen.

Comment: @AmirKhan Thanks! Understood. But why can't the sign up using their phone number?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191306/discussion-between-amir-khan-and-drevival).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our team faced that too. We solved it by providing them with a demo account. 
We set up a phone number and static code to pass to otp. And then we provided them and it worked!